# Why can't I use ttk in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I type `from Tkinter import ttk` it says that there is no module named `ttk`, and also on many websites online the `t` in `tkinter` is always *lowercase*, but when I type `tkinter` in Python it throws an error. Why is that?

Answer (score 34):

There is nothing wrong with the case. As other answer specified - its `Tkinter` in Python 2.x and `tkinter` in Python 3.x version.

In addition `ttk` was a separate module in Python 2.x and its a submodule of Tkinter in Python 3.x

So in Python 2.x you would import ttk as

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
```

And in Python 3.x you would import ttk as

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

or

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Answer (score 13):

`Tkinter` in python 2.6 is capitalized, in python 3 it is lowercase, `tkinter`

Comment: also, in python 2.6 ttk is a stand-alone module but in python 3 it is a submodule of tkinter

Answer (score 4):

To use ttk from Python, you need a separate download and install which you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/python-ttk/).

Python is case-sensitive (like most programming languages), but "many websites" are not (like most human beings) so it's a perfectly understandable sloppiness on those "many websites"' part to spell `Tkinter` in the wrong case.  Hey, you yourself break English rules by using lower case in words starting sentences, *twice* in your short question, you should sympathize with the use of wrong casing in those "many websites", and definitely shouldn't be *surprised* by it!

Comment: Thanks for that answer, i for got that i wasn't the only lazy one, but i was wondering on the site that you gave a link to what should I click on to download ttk? I saw more than one thing to download and i wasn't sure which to pick.

Comment: @g.singh, best is probably http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttk/ -- pypi is often the best repo from which to download Python extensions. Note that it's a .tar.gz file so after download you'll have to unpack it and install it "manually" (python setup.py install with your favorite Python >= 2.5).  Before installing you'll also need ttk separately installed with the Tcl-Tk installation you're using, of course (pyttk is the Python interface to ttk, it is not the ttk functionality itself).

Comment: @AlexMartelli In Python 3 `ttk` is not a separate module, but it is a submodule and you should specify in which versions `ttk` is a submodule or not..

Comment: As pygabriel explains below, the capitalization of the Tkinter module name has nothing to do with laziness, but more to do with which version of python was being used.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question with you.The fact is in Python2.x,
the way to import module is type capitalized "T" in "tkinter":

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

And to import "ttk",you can type this:

```
import ttk
```

It seems like it is no obvious defferrence of module tkinter in py2.x  and py3.x,so just go ahead to use it!good luck!